# devise redirects to sign_in page for no reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using the latest [devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) in a rails 3.0.9 project with ruby 1.8.7 and I am having a small problem.

On occasion when I attempt to load the home page or any public facing page (regardless if the controller requires authorization or not) it seems to render and redirect to the sign in page.

Is there a fix for this?

**update**

just happened in production ...

```
Started GET "/posts/knee-up-back-side-balance-lunge" for IP at Sun Aug 14 08:58:03 -0500 2011
  Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"knee-up-back-side-balance-lunge"}
Rendered posts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (106.7ms)
Completed   in 119ms


Started GET "/admins/sign_in" for IP at Sun Aug 14 08:58:03 -0500 2011
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered partials/_flash.html.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered partials/_sidebaradverts.html.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered partials/_paypaldonate.html.erb (0.6ms)
Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (165.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 184ms (Views: 179.0ms | ActiveRecord: 20.6ms)
```

Like I was saying, not very helpful :(

but if i reload the original page, it won't go to the "/admins/sign_in" controller.
it's kinda annoying as this sometimes happens to the googlebot too and i end up with crawl errors.

**update: routes.rb file included**

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins
  devise_for :accounts
  match "/oauth/create", :to => "oauth#create", :via => "get", :as => "oauth_callback"
  resources :oauth
  resources :movies, :collection => { :import => :get }
  resources :posts
  match 'admin' => 'admin#index'
  root :to => 'index#index'
end
```

Comment: There's definitely a reason, but it's hard to say without specifics. Have you analyzed the log files to see what might be the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. Yes, the log files aren't very helpful in this case unfortunately. My home page is nothing special (standard welcome#index).. when I boot my server all the requests that happen say that the homepage content was rendered (as in all the db requests) but instead it goes to the sign in action. It's definitely set up correctly. When it happens to me again I will add the log content.

Comment: Can you include your routes.rb in the question?

Comment: routes added over a week ago ... still no takers?